# Describing running Linux process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

How to describe (or model) one running Linux process in a specific point of time. Say that the time stopped, and we are looking to a frozen or snapshot of the whole system. What is the process at this moment.

Maybe something like this (it's just an inaccurate list example):

1. a memory space allocated for the process, includes:

   - code section, includes:...
   - data section, includes:...
   - ...
2. cpu registries' values related to the process, includes:

   - program counter
   - ...
3. timers
4. opened files' descriptors
5. some un-returned system calls established by the process,...
6. some un-returned signals handlers caused by outside actors,...
7. ...
8. ...

Is there a reference or source for a comprehensive and accurate information stating a running process.

Comment: Do you need a coredump or what? I can't see a question in your question.

Comment: Not exactly a core dump, I'm trying to analyze processes behavior, that is why I need to specify and list all the aspects and details that control, affect and form a living running process.
(During my work, in every review I made, I discovered some missed aspects.)

Comment: This is a hard question but I'd say look up https://criu.org/Main_Page. This tool literally freezes a running process and moves it. It handles _all_ things needed for that. So probably a starting point